# Use the aggregate method with $unwind to parse out the scores array, followed by a $group and a $sum

Tags: mongodb

What I'm trying to do is add up the sum of the scores for any German Restaurant in Manhattan. I want to return the top 5 restaurants with their name and total score.

Here is the setup of the json data I'm working with:

```
{
  "address": {
     "building": "1007",
     "coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
     "street": "Morris Park Ave",
     "zipcode": "10462"
  },
  "borough": "Bronx",
  "cuisine": "Bakery",
  "grades": [
     { "date": { "$date": 1393804800000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 2 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1378857600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 6 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1358985600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 10 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1322006400000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 9 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1299715200000 }, "grade": "B", "score": 14 }
  ],
  "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
  "restaurant_id": "30075445"
}
```

I've tried multiple variations of this:

```
 db.restaurants.aggregate([{$unwind: "$grades"}, {$group: {_id: {borough: "Manhattan", cuisine:"German"}, total:{$sum:"scores"}}}])
```

And this is what keeps getting returned. I'm new to MongoDb and I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
{ "_id" : { "borough" : "Manhattan", "cuisine" : "German" }, "total" : 0 }
```

Comment: Please define "top 5 restaurants".  Is this the 5 restaurants with the highest average rating, or the 5 restaurants with the most cumulative score, or the 5 restaurants with the most reviews, etc.?

Comment: I could see a restaurant with one review with a score of 1000 but this might be biased since there is only one review

Comment: Each restaurant has a few scores in an array with a grade. I want to add up all the scores so for the example above it would be 41. Then I need to sort fall of the German Restaurants in manhattan and return the top 5 restaurants with the highest total score.

Comment: See answer below...

Answer (score 1):

So here is an aggregation that might work assuming the average score is what is measured...

**Query:**

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
    { $match: {  "borough": "Manhattan", "cuisine": "German" } },
    { $unwind: "$grades" },
    { $group: {
        "_id": "$name",
        "avg_score": { $avg: "$grades.score" }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { "avg_score": -1 } },
    { $limit: 5 } 
]).pretty()
```

**Pipeline Explaination:**

1. match on borough and cuisine to filter to only desirable conditions
2. Unwind the grades array to flatten structure for review
3. group on the restaurant name and get the average score
4. Sort on the average score descending to get the top scores at the
   top of the list
5. Limit output to the top 5 restaurants.

**EDIT:**

Sort by sum instead of average...

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
    { $match: {  "borough": "Manhattan", "cuisine": "German" } },
    { $unwind: "$grades" },
    { $group: {
        "_id": "$name",
        "avg_score": { $avg: "$grades.score" },
        "sum_score": { $sum: "$grades.score" }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { "sum_score": -1 } },
    { $limit: 5 } 
]).pretty()
```

Comment: @user12216544 - glad to help!

Comment: This is a good example of how $unwind works, as without it, the avg_score & sum_score would be null and 0, respectively. 
Note that pretty() has no effect as it's beautified by default.